# TeamCity error: Executable file to start couldn't be found on path svn

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2012, teamcity-8.0

[image: enabling subversion in TeamCity error]

What would be the solution to that problem?
Where can I find that svn.exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I resolved this issue.

1.go to https://subversion.apache.org/packages.html

2.Install Win32Svn

3.In the upper window (see question) put path to svn C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\bin\svn.exe

4. Put path to solution directory

That's it :-)